# ListView with CheckedTextView and icon checks wrong item on Android 2.x devices

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I have a ListView with a bunch of items having an icon, text and a checkbox.

The layout for the list row looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_icon"
        ... />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"        
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

the list is filled using:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> datalist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();
for (Item item : mItems) {
        HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("info", item.info);
        data.put("icon", item.icon);
        datalist.add(data);
}

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), datalist, R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { "info", "icon" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1, R.id.list_icon });

list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

the onItemClick handler looks like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    if (ctv != null) {
        ctv.setChecked(!ctv.isChecked());
    }
}
```

When i fill the app with three list items and click on the last item, on Android 2.x devices
the first item will get checked, if i click again, the last item will get checked. 
The list gets filled again each time i click on an item and the order seems to change.

I checked in the onItemClick handler that the CheckedTextView delivered is the actual view that holder
the string of the item i click, but still another item gets checked.

Any idea what's going on here?
I assume that this might be caused by the shared views in the adapter... (convertView). If so
how can I circumvent that issue?

Thanks in advance.